# How to prevent multiple object/picture on each other?

Tags: c#, xna

With a xbox control when i press Y I want a trap to appear, and it does, but i dont want the traps to be above each other, it should not work to place the a trap then.
I am able to place how much as I want right now, but when I place a trap above another it is possible, but after that I can't place any more traps. The trap class has a hitbox. Here is my code.

```
if (Ypress == true)
        {
            canPlace = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < trapList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (trapList[i] != trap && trapList[i].hitBox.Intersects(trap.hitBox))
                {
                    canPlace = false;
                }
            }

            if (canPlace)
            {
                trap = new Trap(pos, TextureManager.archerTrap, new Point(50, 50), new Point(3, 1), 2000, true);
                trapList.Add(trap);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the look of the code you posted, during the loop, `trap` will most likely be `null` or a value you dont want.

Move the `trap = new Trap(...)` code to before the for loop (Where `canPlace = true;` is) so that the trap you are checking collision is the trap that you are about to place. If it turns out you cannot place that trap, then all you have to do is skip over the `trapList.Add(trap);` line and you're sorted (Presuming `trap` isn't used elsewhere).